# Exchange 2010 Sp2 Prepare Domain the parameter 'preparead' cannot have a value

Tags: exchange-2010

I try to install Exchange 2010 Sp2 on a fresh environment (the first Exchange server in the environment ) and I do all the Prerequisites and I prepare the 2003 DC by the windows server 2008 preparation tool (that cam in the windows server 2008 DVD )

and I run the setup /ps command from windows server 2008 R2 join to the domain (the server that I will install the Exchange 2010 SP2 on) and it is Success

the problem is when I apply the setup /p on:myname.com command this error came up

the parameter 'preparead' cannot have a value

Any help, I will be grateful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the exact command you ran, then you're missing a slash:

```
setup /p /on:myname.com
```